# Powershell IF Else Statements - Perform an action if two or more files in folder contain specific wildcard name

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am attempting to create a IF Else statement that will preform an action only if two or more files contain a specific file name, else if only 1 preform a different action

E.g of fileName

1. Logfile.txt
2. MainLogFile.txt

The wildcard is * Logfile *

Sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
If folder contains >=2 with filename *Logfile* { #Not sure how to create this

    $filenameFormat = "LogFile" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt"
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Interface\Logfile.txt" -NewName $filenameFormat
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Interface\*Logfile*.txt" | 
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
        Select-Object -Last 1 | 
        Remove-Item -Force
} 
elif folder contains 1 with filename *Logfile* {  #Not sure how to create this
    
    $filenameFormat = "LogFile" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt"
    Rename-Item -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Interface\Logfile.txt" -NewName $filenameFormat
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` and count the number of items returned:

```
$path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Interface'
if(@(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *LogFile* -File).Count -ge 2){
    # ...
}
```